# Command to run a bat script against all filename in a folder and segmented databases and merging output

Tags: python, perl, batch-file, cmd

I have a random number (and with random name) of .txt files within a folder named 'seq' as:

```
NP_4500.1.txt
NP_4568.1.txt
NP_45981.3.txt
XM_we679.txt
36498746.txt
```

in another folder named 'db', I made a database fragmented in 20 segments (due to my computational limitations) which are arranged as:

```
hg.part-01.db
hg.part-02.db
hg.part-03.db
..
..
hg.part-20.db
```

now I want to run the following command in each  .txt file against each fragmented database and generate fragmented result, as for one .txt file (NP_4500.1.txt):

```
script.exe ./seq/NP_4500.1.txt -db ./db/hg.part-01.db -out NP_4500.1_part-01.out
script.exe ./seq/NP_4500.1.txt -db ./db/hg.part-02.db -out NP_4500.1_part-02.out
script.exe ./seq/NP_4500.1.txt -db ./db/hg.part-03.db -out NP_4500.1_part-03.out
...
...
script.exe ./seq/NP_4500.1.txt -db ./db/hg.part-20.db -out NP_4500.1_part-20.out
```

After that, I want to merge the results in a single file as:

```
join NP_4500.1_part-001.out NP_4500.1_part-002.out .. NP_4500.1_part-00200.out > NP_4500.1.out
```

similarly for next .txt file:

```
NP_4568.1.txt

...
```

Now, I can run a cmd script for each .txt file as:

```
for %%F in ("*.txt") do script.exe ./seq/%%F .......
```

But my question is, how can I integrate this command with each of the fragmented database and merge the .out files to generate result for a single .txt file before proceeding to the next.

I am using windows 7 (32 bit machine). I can use cmd, perl or python script. Thanks for ur consideration.

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (
 'dir /b /a-d "%sourcedir%\*.txt" '
 ) DO (
 SET "join="
 FOR /L %%d IN (101,1,120) DO (
  SET /a segment=%%d
  SET "segment=!segment:~-2!"
  ECHO(script.exe %sourcedir%\%%a -db .\db\hg.part-!segment!.db -out %%~na_part-!segment!.out
  SET "join=!join! %%~na_part-!segment!.out"
 )
 ECHO(join !join! ^>%%~na.out
)


GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the setting of `sourcedir` to suit your circumstances.

Note that in windows the directory-separator is `\` - '/` is a switch-indicator.

The outer `for` assigns each filename in turn to `%%a`.

`%%d` is assigned 100..120 in turn. This is assigned to `segment` and then only the last 2 characters of `segment` are used.

The `script.exe` is then run for each segment, and the `join` string builds up each `.out` filename.

Finally, the `join` command is executed.

The required commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. **After you've verified that the commands are correct**, delete the string `ECHO(` which appears before your command to actually execute the commands. You would also need to change the `^>` in the final `echo` to `>` - the caret escapes the special meaning of `>` for the purpose of being `echo`ed.

The `%~na` Hieroglyph means the name part only of the string in `%%a`